# TeX Programming

Tags: tex-core

I have lot of confusion regarding TeX and LaTeX. What I have understood is TeX is basically macro instructions, and LaTeX uses that macros or we can say TeX is extended to LaTeX.

But, really not very clear. Can I get a simple def of TeX and a example of TeX?

Is the TeX program executed in a same way like LaTeX? That is creating .tex file and then converting into .dvi and pdf?

Comment: It's like a programming language and it's major library. TeX the language and LaTeX is the front end library that makes things easier and extends its interaction with other media such as PDF objects, colors in a rather more convenient way. But I think this is a duplicate of one that I can't find now